# how to extracts icons positions from desktop screenshot in python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, pyautogui

I want to extract coordinates of theses icon ,How can I do this using python
Any help will be appreciated [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOMZb.jpg)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it help you?

```
def get_pos_x(col):
    return (col - 1) * 51 + 1

def get_pos_y(row):
    return 4 + (row - 1) * 56 + (row - 1) * 11 + 1

icon = (51, 56) # width * height

col = 2
row = 2

print(get_pos_x(col))
print(get_pos_y(row))
```

Each icon needs on your screen 51 pixels in width and 56 pixels in height. In addition, consider the distance to the first row of 4 pixels and between the rows of 11 pixels. I've added a pixel to x and y so that you can get to the next icon.

Comment: I want do this through image processing

Comment: I think that could be too big for your problem. You may want to describe your problem above in more detail. I point out: You could start an application directly or you could use pywinauto (https://pywinauto.github.io/).